# Django Rest Framework error: {"user":["This field is required."]

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When posting this:

```
curl -X POST  -H "Authorization: Token sometoken" -d "url=someurl" 127.0.0.1:8000/create/
```

I get the error:

> {"user":["This field is required."] with the ItemSerializer,

I have seen other posts on SO talking about using perform_create, which I am trying to use to save the user object, but it doesn´t work for some reason. Perform_create works when user is defined like this:

```
user = serializers.CharField(
    default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)
```

But I want to use the user object, not only CharField storing the username

Serializers:

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = UserModel
    fields = ('pk', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    read_only_fields = ('email', )


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ['cat']

 class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
         model = Comment
         fields = [
             'comment',

         ]

class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     user = UserDetailsSerializer()
     category = CategorySerializer(many=True)
     thecomments = CommentSerializer(many=True)
     timestamp = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_mytimestamp')

     def get_mytimestamp(self, obj):
         return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())

     class Meta:
         model = Item

         fields = [
         "url",
         "user",
         "timestamp",
         "categories",
         "thecomments",
    ]
```

Model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', unique=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

View:

```
class ItemCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
     serializer_class = ItemSerializer

     def perform_create(self, serializer):
         serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Solution:

Serializer to create Item:

```
class CreateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     timestamp = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_mytimestamp')

     def get_mytimestamp(self, obj):
         return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())

     class Meta:
         model = Item

         fields = [
         "url",
         "timestamp",
         ]
```

views.py

```
class ItemCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
     serializer_class = CreateSerializer

     def perform_create(self, serializer):
         serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

post:

```
curl -X POST  -H "Authorization: Token sometoken" -d "url='someurl'" 127.0.0.1:8000/createitem/
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     user = UserDetailsSerializer()
     category = CategorySerializer(many=True)
     thecomments = CommentSerializer(many=True)
     timestamp = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_mytimestamp')

     def get_mytimestamp(self, obj):
         return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())

     class Meta:
         model = Item

         fields = [
         "url",
         "user",
         "timestamp",
         "categories",
         "thecomments",
         ]
        extra_kwargs = {'user': {'required': False}}
```

add `extra_kwargs = {'user': {'required': False}}` to your serializer Meta

Comment: I still get the same error, but it must be in the right direction, makes sense to have something like {'user': {required:False}}. I also tried    
user = UserDetailsSerializer(required=False, read_only=True)
But it gives:  The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `app.serializers.ItemSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

Comment: Btw the 'This field is required' error does not appear when using get requests, this has to do with creating the user object when posting.

Comment: delete `user = UserDetailsSerializer()` in `ItemSerializer` when post all will fine,different serializer for post and get

Answer (score 0):

If the field you are having problems with, is part of a unique key, DRF serializer checker will throw the validation error even if you have marked the field as optional (i.e.: `blank=True, null=True`), or even if you have used the other answers' suggestion (i.e.: `extra_kwargs = {'user': {'required': False}}`).

Although if this happens, you will probably need to review your model design, as in my case :)

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue.
added `extra_kwargs = {'user': {'required': False}}` to **serializer** Meta class and it worked

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31912641)