# ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required' )

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

Hi I am new to django html and I have been making a CRUD with Products having categories,sub categories,colors,size using SERIALIZERS.When I am trying to add a  the data isnt getting displayed on webpage heres the error:
"{'category_name': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}"
below is the model of categories:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    #made changes to category_name for null and blank
    category_name = models.ForeignKey(Products,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category_description = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

below are the show and insert functions

```
def show_cat(request):
    showcategory = Categories.objects.filter(isactive=True)
    #print(showall)
    serializer = CategoriesSerializer(showcategory,many=True)
    #print(serializer.data)
    return render(request,'polls/show_cat.html',{"data":serializer.data})

def insert_cat(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        insertcategory = {}
        insertcategory['category_name.id']=request.POST.get('category_name')
        insertcategory['category_description']=request.POST.get('category_description')
        form = CategoriesSerializer(data=insertcategory)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print("hkjk",form.data)
            messages.success(request,'Record Updated Successfully...!:)')
            return redirect('categories:show_cat')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return redirect('categories:show_cat')
    else: 
        return render(request,'polls/insert_cat.html')
```

below are the htmls of insert and show respetively

```
<tr>
                        <td>Category Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="category_name" placeholder="CATEGORIES">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="category_description" id="" cols="30" rows="10">

                            </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

```
 <td><b>{{result.category_name}}</b></td>
          <td><b>{{result.category_description}}</b></td>
          <td style="position: relative;left:50px;">
            <a href="categories/edit_cat/{{result.id}}">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square">EDIT</i>
              </button>
            </a>
          </td>
```

where am I going wrong in the code?

Comment: Hey Ameya please refer this question for your problem Django Rest Framework error: {"user":["This field is required."] - Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842120/django-rest-framework-error-userthis-field-is-required

Comment: Is there any special reason why you are using a serializer and not a Django Form? Also you shouldn't need a serializer to render your `show_cat.html`

Comment: my senior has told me to use a serializer Bernhard